# Change the notification setting on the lock screen

Tags: notifications, samsung-galaxy-s-4

After the recent software update, I have been getting notifications from apps like the Messenger app appearing on my lock screen. Originally, I would just get a popup in the toolbar at the top of the screen.

Is there any way I can change the notifications back to that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
***Settings*** -> ***Sounds and Notifications*** -> now under ***Notifications*** there is an option called ***Notifications on lock screen*** ,on tapping on it you get various options like *Show content* ,*Hide content*, ***Do not show notifications***. Choose your desired option!!